# Python-social-auth: disable autoregistering new users

Tags: django, facebook, python-social-auth

I'm experiencing problems with setting PSA not to register a new user on a login.
The [documentation](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pipeline.html#authentication-pipeline) says:

`It’s possible to override it by defining the setting SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE, for example a pipeline that won’t create users, just accept already registered ones would look like this:`

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details'
)
```

I add this code to my settings, try to login via Facebook with an already registered user, and after that I'm redirected to default `/accounts/login/#_=_` page.

With the default pipeline settings everything works fine and I'm able to log in.

Comment: the documentation was wrong on that example, I've updated it to a valid value. Basically you need these tree entries at the top of your pipeline: ``'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details', 'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid', 'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As omab pointed out, working code is

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details', 
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',      
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details'
 )`
```